# Telling Vim to use custom .vimrc is easy, but how to tell it to use alternative path instead of ~/.vim?

Tags: command-line, vim, vimrc

I can use `vim -u filename` to use `filename` instead of my default `.vimrc`. I am using this method when switching user contexts (`su`) to use *my* `.vimrc` even though running as superuser.

How can I achieve the same *also* for the folder which by default is `~/.vim` so that I can point Vim **from the command line** to an alternative folder?

---

### What I want to achieve

Okay, assume user `joe` (`HOME=/home/joe`) and user `root` (`HOME=/root`). User `joe` has an alias set for `vim` which looks like this (but originally set using the `$HOME` variable to make this dynamic):

```
alias vim='vim -p -N -n -i NONE -u "/home/joe/.vimrc"'
```

Then user `joe` does something along the lines of `sudo su -` (but with added magic), resulting in the `.bashrc` and other goodies from `/home/joe` to be loaded for `root`. User `root` has now the exact same alias for `vim` set as shown above.

The problem is that this `.vimrc` is used on various systems and in various scenarios. Often Joe's account is called `joe`, but sometimes it'll be something like `local.joe` or whatever else, resulting in a different value for `$HOME`. So hard coding an absolute path to the `~/.vim` folder doesn't seem to be a good idea. However, in our above scenario user `root` doesn't have a folder `/root/.vim` which, however, is expected to exist by default via the loaded `.vimrc` (`/home/joe/.vimrc`).

What I want to achieve - preferably on the command line - is to get Vim to use plugins etc from underneath `/home/joe/.vim` when started as `root` (assuming the `alias` is set as shown - other cases can be ignored). If there is some dynamic method via VimScript, please provide pointers. But using variables such as `$HOME` would lead to a catch 22, I think.

Comment: you can probably get this done with good old `ln`. like 'mv ~/.vim ~/.vim-whatever && ln -s ~/.vim-whatever ~/.vim` then do the same for `.vimrc`. wrap all that up with some bash alias so you can easily switch one way or the other

Comment: I found very practical to use `sudoedit` instead, letting you edit files as `superuser` with your `EDITOR`, without any supplementary configuration

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vim looks in ~/.vim because that directory is in the default list in 'runtimepath', abbreviated as 'rtp'. To tell Vim to look elsewhere, you will have to completely specify a different 'rtp' value, or edit the default using a call to substitute() for example. If you just want Vim to look in a different place for your configuration files first, don't care that it also looks in ~/.vim, and don't care that it doesn't look in your alternative after directory, the command is pretty simple:

```
vim --cmd 'set rtp^=alternate_dir'
```

See

```
:help --cmd
:help :set^=
```

Replacing .vim with your alternative directory takes a little more typing.

```
vim --cmd 'let &rtp = substitute(&rtp, "\.vim", "alternate", "g")'
```

I tried replacing `~/.vim` with another path, but I couldn't match the `~`, so I went ahead and posted what I had.

**Edit**

The reason I could not match the `~` in the value of 'rtp' is that when the value is obtained as the value of `&rtp` rather than the output of `:set rtp?`, the `~` is expanded to the full path name of the user's home directory. There is no `~` in the result.

The following works.

```
vim --cmd 'let &rtp = substitute(&rtp, $HOME."/\.vim", "alternate", "g")'
```

Comment: thanks a bunch for taking the time to answer. This looks *very* promising. I'll tinker with this a little tomorrow and let you know how it goes. I wish my VimScript fu was stronger, but I am working on it and this points into a promising direction.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: the way you showed it `\\~` does the job. One escape for Bash, I reckon? Anyway this still doesn't work, because something is different about how VimScript handles the `~`.

Comment: I think I have it. Notice that `:set rtp?` shows "~/.vim" but that `:echo &rtp` expands `~` to the full path name. The following seems to work: `vim --cmd 'let &rtp = substitute(&rtp, $HOME."/\.vim", "alternate", "g")'. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks, very interesting and subtle difference. Makes some things more problematic for my specific case, but I'm going to accept. This got me a lot further.

Answer (score 3):

In the .vimrc you choose, you can specify the runtime path:

```
let &runtimepath=/path/to/specific/vim/folder
```

If you are using your person `.vimrc` then you could set this to your personal `.vim` directory and it should work both as `su` and your normal account.

Comment: This isn't exactly from the command line. Is there any way to make this dynamic or so? See, I suppose if I were to use something like `$HOME` then in my own account it'd resolve to `/home/joe` but as root still to `/root` ... so nothing is won. This `.vimrc` is supposed to work across platforms and Vim versions and setting an absolute path totally breaks that. Thanks for taking the time to answer, though.

Comment: @0xC You are already specifying the vimrc from the command line, and this in turn specifies the runtime path.  Note that in the vimrc you can run scripts to define variables, so if you edit your question with the exact outcome we can probably work out a way to do it.

Comment: edited my question. Thanks for the patience :)

Comment: In the users `.bashrc`, could you set variable, say `$REALHOME`, that is exempt from the `sudo` `reset_env` and then use that as the basis for `rtp`?

Comment: It sounds like *one* viable option. I found it easier to smuggle variables this way, however: `alias sudosu='sudo su -l root -c "REALHOME='\''/home/joe'\'' /bin/bash --rcfile /home/joe/.bashrc"'`